# Inconsistent Space Between List Items

Tags: spacing, vertical-spacing, bullets

This is the document that I have right now (`\it`, `\eit`, and `\sit` are just macros that I use for list items):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\def \sit {\begin{itemize}}
\def \eit {\end{itemize}}
\def \it {\item}
\def \bo #1{\textbf{#1}}
\def \ita #1{\textit{#1}}

\title{AP Psychology Unit 7 Notes}
\author{Name}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    \begin{singlespace*}
    \maketitle
    
    \section*{7.1: Theories of Motivation}

    \sit
        \it \bo{Motivation}: desire that is directed towards a specific goal
        \sit
            \it primary needs: needs that are biological (food, water)
            \it secondary needs: psychological (social interaction)
        \eit
        % ...
        \sit
            \it Past experiences: having done something before
            \it \ita{Vicarious experience}: see someone else perform a task and succeed
            \it Social persuation: when others give encouragment
            \it Physiological feedback: how the body reacts; depends on perception
            \it can be subjectively perceived by different individuals, and the perspective can change throughout one's lifetime
        \eit 
    \eit
        
    \end{singlespace*}
\end{document}
```

Everything works fine so far. Now, I'll add one last (sub)list item at the end of the document:

```
% ...
        \sit
            % ...
            \it can be subjectively perceived by different individuals, and the perspective can change throughout one's lifetime

            % this is the new item that I added
            \it some new bullet here, maybe make it long enough so that it spans another two lines at the end of the first page
        \eit 
    \eit
        
    \end{singlespace*}
\end{document}
```

What troubles me is that, when you see the two documents side by side, it's clear that the spacing is inconsistent, as the new bullet's addition reduced the vertical space between list items:
[image: inconsistent space]

Is there any way for me to get rid of the inconsistency, in other words, **let bullet points have the same height regardless of other content on the page**? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `\raggedbottom` versus `\flushbottom` ?

Comment: That solves the case -- thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because sloved in comments.